# How Do I Copy Corda Production Env To Dev For Debugging?

Tags: corda

Very often in enterprise applications, something doesn't work as expected and you need to debug and create a fix.

Obviously you can't test in production as you might have to save something in order to debug it, and you don't want to be responsible for accidentally sending a $1M transaction by mistake!

With traditional applications, this process is done by copying the database from production to a dev environment (maybe redacting sensitive data) and duplicating and debugging the problem there.

In Corda you have multiple nodes involved, the nodes have specific keys and the network has a truststore hierarchy.

What is the process to replicate the production structure and copy all the data from production to development in order to debug?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how complicated your setup is.

- The easy way to rigorously do this is within a mocknetwork during unit testing. (this is the most common setup, example here: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Advanced/obligation-cordapp/workflows/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/samples/obligation/flow/IOUSettleFlowTests.kt)
- Something I like to do a lot is to use intellij breakpoints in the flow / unit tests in order to be sure something works the way i expect.
- Another way to do it is potentially using the testnet (again depends on your use case) https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/corda-testnet-intro.html
- Another way to do this is to write up a script to perform all of the transactions you want the nodes to do while running them locally on your machine just by using the corda shell on all the local nodes and feeding the transactions directly that way.

Copying data from production to apply to local network is gonna be hard because you can't fake all the transactions / state history without a lot of really painful editing of all the tables on each node.

Comment: The only relevant part of this answer is the last sentence "copying .. is gonna be hard..."